# AWS GET request returning network error when called from client

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I have a GET function elseware in the project to list all items in my dynamodb, which works perfectly, however when i use it again but target an item with a specific id, i get this network error. I have ran the function in lamdba directly and it works so im a bit confused.

Here is the call:

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { API } from "aws-amplify";

export default function Sites(props) {
  const file = useRef(null);
  const [site, setSite] = useState(null);
  const [content, setContent] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    function loadSite() {
      return API.get("sites", `/sites/${props.match.params.id}`);
    }

    async function onLoad() {
      try {
        const site = await loadSite();
        const { content } = site;

        console.log(content);

        setContent(content);
        setSite(site);
      } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
      }
    }

    onLoad();
  }, [props.match.params.id]);

  return (
  <div className="Sites"></div>
  );
}
```

EDIT:

Also here is the route from the listall items page:

`<AppliedRoute path="/sites/:id" exact component={Sites} props={childProps} />`

Method Code:

```
import * as dynamoDbLib from "./libs/dynamodb-lib";
import { success, failure } from "./libs/response-lib";

export async function main(event, context) {
  const params = {
    TableName: "sites",
    // 'KeyConditionExpression' defines the condition for the query
    // - 'userId = :userId': only return items with matching 'userId'
    //   partition key
    // 'ExpressionAttributeValues' defines the value in the condition
    // - ':userId': defines 'userId' to be Identity Pool identity id
    //   of the authenticated user
    KeyConditionExpression: "userId = :userId",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":userId": event.requestContext.identity.cognitoIdentityId
    }
  };

  try {
    const result = await dynamoDbLib.call("query", params);
    // Return the matching list of items in response body
    return success(result.Items);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return failure({ status: false });
  }
}
```

Also from testing it in AWS API Gateway I receive a 500 error with the following logs:

https://pastebin.com/FHQnZAqt

Comment: Please attach your get method code

Comment: Done @Alex Thanks for the reply

Comment: What do the CloudWatch Logs for the errant Lambda invocation show? Did it actually execute? Did it fail, throw an exception, something else?

Comment: @jarmod I will let you take a look I'm not too knowledgeable on looking at logs, but as I said, when running the method to list all items, it works fine, the issue arises only trying to get a specific one via its Id https://pastebin.com/kapTnzp3

Comment: Also when I get the error and look at the chrome console thing and I click the endpoint link, it says "missing authentication token"

Comment: You may well have a bug in the Lambda. It's critical that you know how to access the logs to debug Lambda. Also important that your code actually logs meaningful diagnostics, so you can problem solve after the fact. It's easy to get to CloudWatch Logs for the Lambda. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-functions-logs.html.

Comment: @jarmod The cloudwatch logs arent what i sent in the pastebin link?

Comment: Ah, thought that was a repeat of the original pastebin. Not a big fan of external links TBH; the key content should be in the question. So, the logs show a programming error with your DynamoDB query. In your table, is `userId` a string type or numeric? What about the `cognitoIdentityId` you are supplying?

Comment: @jarmod It is a string as is the cognito id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206390/discussion-between-jarmod-and-tierno).

Answer (score 1):

My code was missing the implementation for the API GET /user/{id} route and that caused the 500 response.